# Allow loading HTTP resources over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, content-security-policy, mixed-content

Suppose my website is over HTTPS and I need to load a `CSS` or `Object` resource from `HTTP`, how can I do this?

Please note that I'm able to add `Content-Security-Policy` to the response headers over the `HTTPS` websites but I don't exactly know how can I do this. Can someone give me a solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no solution. Modern browsers will deny using non-https resources into pages served by https because you effectively undermine the security model of https this way. CSP will not help because it does not fix the issue. Your only choice is to either serve the site by http or to proxy includes from external non-https sites by your own site. But note that the latter option might affect the security model too, because now these external resources are seen as originating by the same domain as your own content and thus could misuse the same origin policy.

Comment: As the owner of the website, I should be able to decide whether loading HTTP contents are possible or not. Are you sure there is no solution?

Comment: If you don't need the security offered by HTTPS you are free to provide the full content with HTTP instead. But the idea is that any content included into a HTTPS page hould have the same protection as the page itself, because otherwise it could compromise the security of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing the loading of HTTP resources over HTTPS can potentially pose security risks, as it may compromise the security and integrity of the HTTPS connection. However, if you still need to allow this for specific reasons, you can do so by modifying your website's Content Security Policy (CSP) to include the directive upgrade-insecure-requests. This directive instructs the browser to automatically upgrade any HTTP request to HTTPS.