# Mapbox not showing map

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox

I am making a very simple website with 2 API's working together. Everything went rather well until I tried to add some CSS styling to the general website. Then the mapbox map dissapeared and no matter what I do I can't get it back. I would greatly appreciate any help I could get since I have to make this for a deadline tomorrow.

[here's a link to a codepen version][1]

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Where to land</title>
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.9.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main.js" defer></script>
        <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.9.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Geocoder assets -->
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Kies een locatie</h1>

        <div class="buttonGrid">
        <button id="denhaag">Den Haag</button>

        <button id="parijs">Parijs</button>

        <button id="newyork">New York</button>

        <button id="berlijn">Berlijn</button>
        </div>


        <div id="map"></div>



    </body>

    </html>
```

CSS

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nanum+Gothic&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


#map{
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    top: 300px;
}


h1{
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

.buttonGrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5%;


}

button{
    border: none;
    height: 75px;
    font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

JS

```
// Set api token for mapbox
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmFkYXJ0cmlua2V0cyIsImEiOiJjazhyODV0YTIwN21wM2VwNjlyNjR4YmZ2In0.YY70N_F9VoD5-YRisQVojg';

// api token for openWeatherMap
var openWeatherMapUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
var openWeatherMapUrlApiKey = '4f25a5e50352a1b20b607ffd8388234e';

// Determine cities
var cities = [
  {
    name: 'Den Haag',
    coordinates: [4.300700, 52.070498]
  },
  {
    name: 'Parijs',
    coordinates: [2.352222, 48.856614]
  },
  {
    name: 'New York',
    coordinates: [-74.005941, 40.712784]
  },
  {
    name: 'Berlijn',
    coordinates: [13.404954, 52.520007]
  },

];

// Initiate map
//var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  //container: 'map',
  //style: 'mapbox://styles/radartrinkets/ck914s0450uy91irugye9rhkb',
 // center: [4.895168, 52.370216],
 // zoom: 11,

//});

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
  center: [5.508852, 52.142480],
  zoom: 7
});

document.getElementById('denhaag').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [4.300700, 52.070498], essential:true
  });
});



document.getElementById('parijs').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [2.352222, 48.856614], essential:true
  });
});

document.getElementById('newyork').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [-74.005941, 40.712784], essential:true
  });
});

document.getElementById('berlijn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [13.404954, 52.520007], essential:true
  });
});


// get weather data and plot on map
map.on('load', function () {
  cities.forEach(function(city) {
    // Usually you do not want to call an api multiple times, but in this case we have to
    // because the openWeatherMap API does not allow multiple lat lon coords in one request.
    var request = openWeatherMapUrl + '?' + 'appid=' + openWeatherMapUrlApiKey + '&lon=' + city.coordinates[0] + '&lat=' + city.coordinates[1];

    // Get current weather based on cities' coordinates
    fetch(request)
      .then(function(response) {
        if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        // Then plot the weather response + icon on MapBox
        plotImageOnMap(response.weather[0].icon, city)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
      });
  });
});

function plotImageOnMap(icon, city) {
  map.loadImage(
    'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + icon + '.png',
    function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage("weatherIcon_" + city.name, image);
      map.addSource("point_" + city.name, {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [{
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: city.coordinates
            }
          }]
        }
      });
      map.addLayer({
        id: "points_" + city.name,
        type: "symbol",
        source: "point_" + city.name,
        layout: {
          "icon-image": "weatherIcon_" + city.name,
          "icon-size": 1.3
        }
      });
    }
  );
}


  [1]: https://codepen.io/radartrinkets/pen/rNOxGGy
```

Comment: You can try to move all your code (especially the map creation) in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) { /* You code here... */ });`. That's because maybe you are trying to access the div `map` before it's even loaded in the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that's not it. I've just figured out it has to do with overflow. But I can't seem to target the map (or its container) to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here:

1.) The `#map` CSS is breaking Mapbox GL JS's ability to size itself properly.

2.) The weather icon is being loaded insecurely (over HTTP), which causes the icon to [be blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517391/allow-loading-http-resources-over-https).

The code in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pj_leonard/pen/vYNLqMN) (and below) addresses both of these:

```js
// Set api token for mapbox
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicmFkYXJ0cmlua2V0cyIsImEiOiJjazhyODV0YTIwN21wM2VwNjlyNjR4YmZ2In0.YY70N_F9VoD5-YRisQVojg';

// api token for openWeatherMap
var openWeatherMapUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
var openWeatherMapUrlApiKey = '4f25a5e50352a1b20b607ffd8388234e';

// Determine cities
var cities = [
  {
    name: 'Den Haag',
    coordinates: [4.300700, 52.070498]
  },
  {
    name: 'Parijs',
    coordinates: [2.352222, 48.856614]
  },
  {
    name: 'New York',
    coordinates: [-74.005941, 40.712784]
  },
  {
    name: 'Berlijn',
    coordinates: [13.404954, 52.520007]
  },
  
];

// Initiate map
//var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  //container: 'map',
  //style: 'mapbox://styles/radartrinkets/ck914s0450uy91irugye9rhkb',
 // center: [4.895168, 52.370216],
 // zoom: 11,
  
//});

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v11',
  center: [5.508852, 52.142480],
  zoom: 7
});

document.getElementById('denhaag').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [4.300700, 52.070498], essential:true
  });
});



document.getElementById('parijs').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [2.352222, 48.856614], essential:true
  });
});

document.getElementById('newyork').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [-74.005941, 40.712784], essential:true
  });
});

document.getElementById('berlijn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  map.flyTo({
    center: [13.404954, 52.520007], essential:true
  });
});


// get weather data and plot on map
map.on('load', function () {
  cities.forEach(function(city) {
    // Usually you do not want to call an api multiple times, but in this case we have to
    // because the openWeatherMap API does not allow multiple lat lon coords in one request.
    var request = openWeatherMapUrl + '?' + 'appid=' + openWeatherMapUrlApiKey + '&lon=' + city.coordinates[0] + '&lat=' + city.coordinates[1];
    // Get current weather based on cities' coordinates
    fetch(request)
      .then(function(response) {
        if(!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        // Then plot the weather response + icon on MapBox
        plotImageOnMap(response.weather[0].icon, city)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR:', error);
      });
  });
});

function plotImageOnMap(icon, city) {
  map.loadImage(
    'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + icon + '.png',
    function (error, image) {
      if (error) throw error;
      map.addImage("weatherIcon_" + city.name, image);
      map.addSource("point_" + city.name, {
        type: "geojson",
        data: {
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: [{
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Point",
              coordinates: city.coordinates
            }
          }]
        }
      });
      map.addLayer({
        id: "points_" + city.name,
        type: "symbol",
        source: "point_" + city.name,
        layout: {
          "icon-image": "weatherIcon_" + city.name,
          "icon-size": 1.3
        }
      });
    }
  );
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map{
 display: block;
 height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}


h1{
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}

.buttonGrid{
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 grid-gap: 5%;


}

button{
 border: none;
 height: 75px;
 font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Where to land</title>
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.9.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main.js" defer></script>
        <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.9.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="styles/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Geocoder assets -->
        <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v4.4.2/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Kies een locatie</h1>

        <div class="buttonGrid">
        <button id="denhaag">Den Haag</button>

        <button id="parijs">Parijs</button>

        <button id="newyork">New York</button>

        <button id="berlijn">Berlijn</button>
        </div>


        <div id="map"></div>



    </body>

    </html>
```